# OS X run and detach script from current shell

Tags: macos, bash, shell, unix

I need to launch a script that will act like a daemon from another script and will not prevent me from being able to close Terminal window.

[image]

I tried these standard solutions inside my script :

```
./myscript.sh arg1 arg2 &
```

Or this

```
nohup ./myscript.sh arg1 arg2 &
```

but they all prevent me from being able to close Terminal window
I don't need any output from that subsidiary script.

Do you know a way to do that in standard UNIX shell, or if I can find some builtin commands or services on Mac to ask to run that script on my behalf.

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This might work:

```
xterm -e 'sh /path/to/script.sh' &
```

You may also want to include the `-hold` option as well.

Comment: I don't have the `terminal` command on my machine. Where does it come from?

Comment: @jtbandes - it comes from my imagination, caused by trying to answer the qu without a mac to hand - answer edited